# Holomorphic operators, what does it mean?

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

It is clear for me what means that a function is holomorphic, but what about operators? What does it mean that an operator is holomorphic?

In particular, consider the free Dirac operator
$$ H_0 = -i\alpha\cdot\nabla + m\beta,$$
with $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha, \beta$ are just Hermitian $4\times 4$ matrices.

Is this operator holomorphic? Could anyone explain me why or give me some references?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Where exactly did you see the expression "holomorphic operator"? It could be a shorthand for holomorphic operator valued function or for a generator of a holomorphic semigroup, but does not mean anything without context.

Comment: I read this expression in a Kato's paper. He says that $H_0 + kV$ is an holomorphic family of type (A), where $H_0$ denotes the free Dirac operator and $V$ is such a potential.  I don't know what means "holomorphic" for an operator (and then for a family of operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression is presumably taken from [Kato's Remarks on Holomorphic Families of Schrödinger and Dirac Operators](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304020808737137), where he talks not about holomorphic operators but about "*holomorphic **families** $T(κ) = T + κA$ of linear operators in a Hilbert space*". For definitions we are sent to [Kato's book Perturbation theory for linear operators, ch. VII.1.2](https://books.google.com/books/about/Perturbation_theory_for_linear_operators.html?id=k-7nCAAAQBAJ). When the operators in the family are bounded "holomorphic" means just what one would expect, i.e. $T(κ)$ is complex differentiable (strongly or weakly, it does not make a difference which). Kato calls this "bounded-holomorphic". But since the Schrödinger and Dirac operators are unbounded the definition becomes more complicated and technical:

> "*A family of operators $T(κ)\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ defined in a neighborhood of $κ = 0$ is said to be holomorphic at $κ = 0$ (in the generalized sense) if there is a third Banach space $Z$ and two families of operators $U(κ)\in\mathcal{C}(Z,X)$ and $V(κ)\in\mathcal{C}(Z,Y)$ which are bounded-holomorphic at $κ = 0$ such that $U(κ)$ maps $Z$ onto $D(T(κ))$ one to one and $T(κ)U(κ)=V(κ)$. $T(κ)$ is holomorphic in a domain D of the complex plane if it is holomorphic
>   at every $κ$ of $D$.*"

This is motivated by the notion of generalized convergence of closed operators introduced in chapter IV of the same book which generalizes to them the notion of convergence by norm of bounded operators. As for type (A), we find that in VII.2.1:

> "*A family $T(κ)\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$, defined for $κ$ in a domain $D_0$ of the complex plane, is said to be holomorphic of type (A) if i) $D(T(x)) = D$ is independent
>   of $κ$ and ii) $T(κ)u$ is holomorphic for  $κ\in D_0$ for every $u\in D$.*"

Holomorphic type (A) families of Dirac operators are briefly discussed in section VII.3.3 of the book.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Conifold! Something now is a little bit clearer now. However, I refer to the Kato's paper "Holomorphic families of DIrac operators". My question was motivated by his remark (a) on page 400 of the above mentioned paper:" Theorem I, (iii), implies that $H_0 + kV$ forms a holomorphic family of type (A)." Could you hlep me to justify this statement? Your answer is clear, but I still have many difficulties to understand this thing.

Comment: @C.Bishop I added his definition of type (A) families. As for justifying it, I am afraid I do not know enough about Dirac operators and potentials, sorry. In VII.3.3 he only says that for Schrodinger operators it follows from relative (to the Laplacian) boundedness of multiplication operators, with bound $0$, and the Dirac case is analogous "if the potential is not too strong".

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help and the patience, @Conifold!